# What does creating a Solution using a template in Visual Studio actually do versus an empty project?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, winmain

I am following the Intro to C tutorial by Molly Rocket but am running into an issue running the following code in the Debugger in VisualStudio 2019 while using the Empty Project option.

I am using the Empty Project option instead of loading a template because that is what Molly used, while I could just load a template and run the code there instead I would like to know why I am getting this error so I can better understand Visual Studio and C++.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void learnC(void) {

    OutputDebugStringA("Test\n");

}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow) 
{
    learnC();
}
```

Recieving the error LNK2019 which doesn't help at all because it just a generic catch all error code.

***error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)***

I have tried updating the compatiliblity settings of VS2019 as well as other settins that people suggested to use but the error still remains.

Again, when I created the Solution I used the blank document instead of a template becuase that is what Molly Rocket used when writing this code.

When I do use a template (I used the Windows Desktop Application template) and delete all the code and paste in what I had in my original document I do not recieve the Error, and I would like to know why.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: ***error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)*** means you need an int main() instead of a WinMain(). This probably is a console application.

Comment: Yes, this works to allow the code to run.

Comment: However, I am curious as to why the original non modified code (WinMain) will run and produce the same result as modified code when the project what created using a Template instead of an Empty Project.

Comment: @TannerFelmlee Create an empty project, create a Windows Desktop project, then compare the generated files. Both the code and project settings are in plain text files that you can compare for differences.

Comment: Just did this and found the solution, posting it now.  I don't know why but I gues I just needed to write down the question in order to find the answer to it,  I found the solution about 20 min after I posted the question.  Maybe I will just make a notepad instead of using stack overflow.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an Empty Project, the value of `SubSystem` defaults to `Console`.

[image]

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2019)

> An application that uses /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE; calls main (or wmain)
>
> An application that uses /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS; calls WinMain (or
>   wWinMain), which must be defined to use __stdcall

As far as I'm concerned you should Set up `SubSystem` to `windows`(**Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem**)

[image]

For more details about `/SUBSYSTEM (Specify Subsystem)`, I suggest you could refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019